# Continuity of preference

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, preferences, definition

"A preference is continuous if for any $a,b\in X$ with $a\succsim b$ there are some neighborhoods $N_{\varepsilon}(a)$, $N_{\delta}(b)$ around $a$ and $b$ such that for every $x \in N_{\varepsilon}(a)$, $y\in N_{\delta}(b)$ we have $x\succsim y$"

Is that true and what is the purpose of continuous preference? Please give me an example.

Answer (score 3):

It would be with strict preference, otherwise it could always be proven to not hold, by taking $a=b$, or even any two points where $a \sim b$.

Well, then that would be true simply because it’s the definition of continuous preference.

An example would be literally any continuous utility function over its domain, such as $x+y$, $x^\frac{1}{3} y^\frac{2}{3}$, $\log(x) + \log(y), \text{min}\{x,y\}$ and many more.

It is much more interesting to think about non-examples.

One non-example is $U(x,y) = x + ⌊y⌋$ where $⌊•⌋$ is the floor function, which rounds down the argument to the previous integer.

Let’s work on the Euclidean metric $d(•,•)$ over ${\mathbb{R}^+}^2$.

Let’s take $a = (1,1)$ and $b = (1,0)$.

We have $U(a) = 2 > 1 = U(b)$, therefore $a \succ b$

Now let $\epsilon \in (0,2) $ be arbitrary.

Let $x = (1-\frac{\epsilon}{2},1-\frac{\epsilon}{2})$.

We have that $d(x,a) = \sqrt{2 (\frac{\epsilon}{2})^2} = \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}} < \epsilon$, hence $x \in N_\epsilon (a)$.

Note $1-\frac{\epsilon}{2} \in (0,1)$, hence $⌊1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}⌋ = 0$.

Therefore, $U(x) = 1-\frac{\epsilon}{2} < 1 = U(b)$, hence $b \succ x$.

Note a point always belongs to its own neighborhood, so we just found $(a,b) \in {\mathbb{R}^+}^2 $ with $a \succ b$, such that for arbitrarily small $\epsilon, \delta > 0$ we can always find $x$ (and $y = b$) such that $x \in N_\epsilon (a)$ and $y \in N_\delta (b)$, but $y \succ x$.

Therefore, we can conclude that the preferences represented by this utility function are not continuous.

The same can be proven for lexicographic preferences for any points of the form $a = (c,a_2), b = (c,b_2)$, where $a_2 > b_2$, as $(c-\frac{\epsilon}{2},a_2) \in N_\epsilon (a)$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon >0$, as $a \succ b$ but $b \succ (c-\frac{\epsilon}{2},a_2)$.

Some purposes of continuous preferences are to be able to draw nice indifference curves and for a Walrasian Equilibrium to exist in pure exchange economies. The latter also requiring strict convexity and strict monotonicity as well.